# datatables external form filtering

Tags: datatables

I'm using jquery datatables (datables.net) and I want to multiple columns filtering. My form is prepackaged and prepared. I do not want to use datables input filtering genereator.

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `fnServerParams` [here the doc + example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)

another example :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "script/server_showapply.php",
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "nameOfparam", "value": $('#idOfInputForm').val() } );
    }

    });

    });
```

### the server-side :

you should have or something like (depends on server) `Request['nameOfparam']` that will have the value of input from your form

for each ajax request of datatable that sends to you, all internal params (`sEcho`, `iTotalRecords`... + your custom params here "nameofparam", you can see them in the log network with your browser (ex Chrome F12 > Network > your request > header request > param send)).

Is it help you?